# Pi Zero MAX98357 EQ & Softvol

Tags: raspberry-pi, alsa

I'm trying to get alsamixer & softvol to work together, but can't figure out how to combine them. They work fine on their own but error out once I try to combine them. Probably because I don't quite understand how it all works together.

I tried placing the `plugequal` as a slave to default, and to softvol afterwards - no luck.
Placing it after after `softvol` from default and then routing to `plugequal` also has the same result.

The error:

```
[src/libout123/modules/alsa.c:80] error: initialize_device(): no configuration available
main: [src/mpg123.c:309] error: out123 error 7: failed to open device
```

My `asound.conf`, `softvol` works.

```
pcm.!default {
  type plug
  slave.pcm softvol
  # slave.pcm plugequal
}

ctl.!default {
  type hw
  card 0
}

ctl.equal {
  type equal
}

pcm.plugequal {
  type equal
  slave.pcm "plughw:0,0"
  # slave.pcm softvol # Nope..
}

pcm.equal {
  type plug
  slave.pcm plugequal
}

pcm.softvol {
  type softvol
  slave {
     pcm dmix
     # pcm plugequal # Yeah, no
     # pcm "plughw:0,0" # Does not work..
  }
  control {
    name "PCM"
    card 0
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you found it out now? I have the same problem. Seen some different configs and tried to combine them with yours, but nothing works together.

Comment: @ygoe Sadly no, this opened a rabbit hole I did not want to go down. If you find a solution, please share it here :)